# Return data aggregated by one column id and data-aligned to another column id

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, crosstab

I have a large table with millions of rows like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    row_id bigint,
    col_id bigint,
    value double precision,
    timestamp timestamp
);
```

Given:

1. `list_row` = a list of `row_id`s (can be ordered if needed)
2. `list_col` = a list of `col_id`s (again, can be ordered if needed)
3. Both lists may be very large (maybe 10s of thousands)
4. The table above may have many millions of entries

How do I (efficiently) return a resource where:

1. Columns are all the `col_id`s present in `list_col` and occur in the same order that the `col_id`s occur in `list_col`
2. Rows are all the `row_id`s present in `list_row` (they need not occur in the same order)
3. Each field contains the `value`s of the given `row_id` and `col_id`s.
4. We are only interested in the most recently recorded `value`s for any `row_id:col_id` pair i.e. use `MAX(timestamp`) or something similar as a filter
5. In the result, if there is no recorded `value` for a given `row_id:col_id` co-ordinate then that field should be `null`.

A visual example to clarify. The initial table:

```
+--------+--------+-------+-----------+
| row_id | col_id | value | timestamp |
+========+========+=======+===========+
|   10   |   20   |  100  | 2016-0... |
|   10   |   21   |  200  | 2015-0... |
|   11   |   20   |  300  | 2016-1... |
|   11   |   22   |  400  | 2016-0... |
+--------+--------+-------+-----------+
```

becomes:

```
                  col_id →
            +-----------------+
            | 20  | 21  | 22  |
            +=====+=====+=====+
row_id (10) | 100 | 200 |     |
   ↓   (11) | 300 |     | 400 |
            +-----+-----+-----+
```

I suspect that the correct answer is to start by creating a temporary table with the target `col_id`s as columns and then do some sort of join. I cannot work out how to do this efficiently. Is it possible to do this without needing a temporary table for each `row_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crosstab()` would work for regular queries:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

But **not** for your case because of:

> 3. Both lists may be very large (maybe 10s of thousands)

That's too many columns for Postgres. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html)

> There is a **limit on how many columns a table can contain**. Depending on
>   the column types, it is between **250 and 1600**. However, defining a
>   table with anywhere near this many columns is highly unusual and often
>   a questionable design.

I suggest to return **arrays** instead. Something like (works for any modern Postgres version):

```
SELECT row_id
     , array_agg(col_id) AS cols
     , array_agg(value)  AS vals
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (row_id, col_id)  --  most recent values for row_id:col_id pair 
          row_id, col_id, value
   FROM   mytable
   WHERE  row_id IN (<long list>)
   AND    col_id IN (<long list>)
   ORDER  BY row_id, col_id, timestamp DESC
   ) sub
GROUP   BY 1;
```

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

A couple of alternative ways to return the data:

```
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('col_id', col_id
                                , 'value' , value)) AS col_values1  -- requires pg 9.4+
     , json_agg(json_build_object(col_id, value))   AS col_values2  -- requires pg 9.4+
     , array_agg(ARRAY[col_id, value])              AS col_values3  -- requires pg 9.5+
     , array_agg(hstore(col_id::text, value::text)) AS col_values4  -- requires pg 8.3+
FROM  ...  -- same as above
```

The last one required the additional module [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is _exactly_ what I needed, and addresses all the design constraints. You are awesome!

Comment: @Paul: Thanks, I added some alternative ways to return the data.